# How do you animate fill with Framer Motion?

Tags: reactjs, animation, svg, framer-motion

I'm using the following to try to animate a simple square from red to green with framer motion. If I use the exact same code with opacity, everything works. Likewise if I transform the square with x and y. But with fill, as soon as the square renders it changes fill, and there is no transition. After a few hours of trying to understand why this is, I can't find an answer.

In the docs it says "For instance, physical properties like x or scale will be animated via a spring simulation. Whereas values like opacity or color will be animated with a tween."

It makes no mention of whether I need to do more to create this tween.

Any help would be hugely appreciated, thanks.

```
  const pathVariants = {
    notSwitched: {
      fill: 'red',
    },
    switched: {
      fill: 'green',
    },
  }
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="600"
      height="300"
      viewBox="0 0 600 300"
    >
      <motion.path
        initial="switched"
        animate="notSwitched"
        variants={pathVariants}
        id="square"
        d="M38,212V88H162V212Z"
      />
    </svg>
  )
```

Comment: Any solutions to this?

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes, try using hex codes

Comment: Thanks Raph117! :)